# Joining concurrent/identical HTTP GET requests?

Tags: ajax, http, browser, get, browser-cache

Do browsers join concurrent identical HTTP GET requests? At least, for static or cache-able content?

That is, if something like this happens:

```
| AJAX/HTTP-GET(resourceX)
| [start download]------------------------------------------->[finish download]
|
|            AJAX/HTTP-GET(resourceX)
|            [start download]--------->etc...
|
+------------------------------------------------------------------> Time
```

Will the browser figure out "Hey you're already trying to download resourceX! Don't try downloading it twice, it won't do anything!"?

**Update:

Now of course, I can go to some site and try downloading a big file (e.g., "BigFile"), and click the link twice; this will (duplicately) download both BigFile and BigFile(1). Granted, it's an error on the user's part, but still...

For cache-able resources (e.g., downloading some javascript file), it seems pretty inefficient if browsers couldn't figure out these duplicates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser won't notice. It acts just like regular HTTP traffic. It *might* cache the request once the first one is finished (if the proper cache-control fields are set), but concurrently, no.